# Possible for a class instance property as a value in an attribute

Tags: c#

I have a static class that contains a whole bunch of instances of my class. All instances of MyThing are defined here.

```
public static class AllMyThings
{
    public static MyThing first { get; } = new MyThing(name = "Foo", otherProperty = "1");
    public static MyThing second { get; } = new MyThing(name = "Bar", otherProperty = "50");
    ...
}
```

Elsewhere in my code, I have methods I would like to add attributes to. I would like the values for these attributes to come from these class instances. Something like this

```
[MyAttribute(AllMyThings.first.name)
public void MyMethod()
```

Doing this gives me the error

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression, or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

I can't define `first` as const, because it's an instance of `MyThing`. The only way I can think of to make this work is to have something like this

```
public static class AllMyThings
    {
        public const string firstName = "Foo";
        public const string secondName = "Bar";

        public static MyThing first { get; } = new MyThing(name = firstName, otherProperty = "1");
        public static MyThing second { get; } = new MyThing(name = secondName, otherProperty = "50");
    }

[MyAttribute(AllMyThings.firstName)
public void MyMethod()
```

but i'd like to avoid other parts of code having to now about `first` and `firstName` as opposed to just `first`.

Is there any other option?

Comment: Your only other option is to reference the `AllMyThings` type inside the behavior of the attribute but you can't pass any values to your attributes outside of the restrictions mentioned in the exception message

Comment: It looks that you are doing something wrong. There should be a valid solution for your case. But the case is unclear. Could you elaborate on real problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: Attributes have to be resolved at compile time, so you can't use things which can change at runtime. What exactly are you trying to do with the attribute?

Comment: There's not really a way to expose a referenced property as a constant. Could you make the constants `internal` so at least the exposure is limited to the current assembly?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way but you have to use reflection for that. Here would be the attribute:

```
[MyAttribute(typeof(AllMyThings), nameof(AllMyThings.first))
public void MyMethod()
```

Now your attribute would compile fine but in order to get the value of the AllMyThings.first.name you would have to get the type of AllMyThings, find the static public property by the name and then retrieve the property value.